# Laravel Backpack Fetch Route missing

Tags: laravel-backpack

In my crudcontroller I have added

```
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\FetchOperation;

    public function fetchTag()
    {
        return $this->fetch(\App\Tag::class);
    }
```

But keep getting an error in console saying 405 Method not allowed for this POST route.  I believe Backpack is to add the route automatically but the route is not found.  Where/How do I add the route for a fetch (following the docs for inline-create)?

Comment: Are you sure you added this to the right controller? A `php artisan route:list` should list all the routes, and help you identify where the fetch route is located. I suspect the field might be calling one route, and your fetch respond to another...

Comment: yes thanks was missing on related controller!